# Deduplicating observations from 2 different datasets but prioritizing one over the other? R

Tags: r, dplyr

so I have two sets of data that I am merging and duplicating. I am using the disctinct_at() function from dlpyr to deduplicate after merging the 2 datasets in R with rbind().

I discovered something interesting but I'm not sure if it's by chance. I have two datasets A & B.
There are duplicates in A & B but B has priority as far as the category I am looking for. So if an observation is in both A & B, I would like to see the category from dataset B.

Here is my code.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame("ID" = c(123,124,125,126),
                "Category" = c("Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red"),
                "Helper" = c("dataset_a","dataset_a","dataset_a","dataset_a" ))


b <- data.frame("ID" = c(127,124,125,128),
                    "Category" = c("Green", "Green", "Orange", "Orange"),
                    "Helper" = c("dataset_b","dataset_b","dataset_b","dataset_b"))


bind_1 <- rbind(a,b)

bind_2 <- rbind(b,a)

bind_final_1<- bind_1 %>% 
  #Unqiue 
  distinct_at(vars(ID), .keep_all = TRUE)

bind_final_2<- bind_2 %>% 
  #Unqiue 
  distinct_at(vars(ID), .keep_all = TRUE)
```

The deduplication has different outputs by changing the bind order. bind_final_1 keeps the category from dataset A. While bind_final 2 keeps the category from dataset B? bind_final_2 has the desired output I am looking for but is this output by chance or is there another piece of code I can add to my distinct_at() to always get this output?

[image]

Comment: Because `distinct` returns first unique row `<data-masking> Optional variables to use when determining uniqueness. If there are multiple rows for a given combination of inputs, only the first row will be preserved. If omitted, will use all variables.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to address this:

First we group by `ID` and use `n()` to count when we have multiple rows for an ID. Then we filter to where `Helper == dataset_b` or `n == 1`. `n == 1` is a unique ID, so we keep it. If `n > 1` then we keep the row for `dataset_b`

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  filter(Helper == "dataset_b" | n == 1) %>%
  arrange(ID)

     ID Category Helper        n
  <dbl> <fct>    <fct>     <int>
1   123 Blue     dataset_a     1
2   124 Green    dataset_b     2
3   125 Orange   dataset_b     2
4   126 Red      dataset_a     1
5   127 Green    dataset_b     1
6   128 Orange   dataset_b     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct output in `bind_final_2` and it is not by chance. It would always return the correct output. `distinct` would always keep the 1st occurrence of unique key (`ID` here) since you are doing `bind_2 <- rbind(b,a)` the rows in `b` would always be ahead than rows in `a`.

Also you can use the following -

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(b, a) %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```